# missing method in CLR wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, clr, wrapper

I'm doing CLR wrapper. It builds successfully. Problem is that when I reference wrapper .dll in c# project `RegisterMessageCallback` method is totally absent. Here is what I see in metadata:

```
public class ATFeedWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        public ATFeedWrapper();

        public sealed override void Dispose();
        public void Login();
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool A_0);
    }
```

And here is wrapper class .h:

```
public ref class ATFeedWrapper
{
public:
    ATFeedWrapper();
    void Login();
    void RegisterMessageCallback(void(*clbck)(string));
    ~ATFeedWrapper();

private:
    ATFeedClient* client;

};
```

and .cpp:

```
    ATFeedWrapper::ATFeedWrapper()
    {
        client = new ATFeedClient();
    }

    void ATFeedWrapper::Login()
    {
        client->Login();
    }

    void ATFeedWrapper::RegisterMessageCallback(void(*clbck)(string))
    {
        client->RegisterMessageCallback(*clbck);
    }

    ATFeedWrapper::~ATFeedWrapper()
    {
        delete client;
    }
```

What's going on? Why is it missing?

Comment: It should be absent, its argument is a function pointer, that is not a managed type.  So C# code could never call it.  You must declare it as a *delegate* instead.

Comment: Can you please show this code as answer? And should I change RegisterMessageCallback method of underliyng ATFeedClient class?

Comment: I know you know what a delegate looks like.  Google Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(), lots and lots of hits, including on this site.